# Undefined symbol: .main

Tags: c

We have installed GCC and libgcc on AIX.

I am busy compiling a C library on the machine and keep getting the following error:

Undefined symbol: .main

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: are you building library or executable, show us some code/makefile

Comment: what is the command line you're using ? I smell some wrong parameter passed to the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using the wrong gcc arguments - probably you are using the same ones you'd use for an executable program (where `main()` is required). The correct arguments depend on what kind of library you want to build (a static one or a dynamic (.so) one)